# How to delete items from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to know how to delete an element from a dictionary, but I am going directly to my case. For example, I have a dictionary like this one

```
dic = {(0, 0, 255): [(255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
       (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
       (0, 255, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
       (255, 255, 0): [],
       (0, 255, 255): [(255, 255, 0)]}
```

My purpose is to delete the key that corresponds to the empty list, that here is (255, 255, 0): [] but I would also like to delete the following tuple (i.e. the key) in all other cases where it is present in the dictionary (therefore as a value).
So I would like to get to have this:

```
dic = {(0, 0, 255): [(0, 255, 255)],
       (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
       (0, 255, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)],
       (0, 255, 255): []}
```

I want to specify the fact that I save each deleted key in a list, in fact I used this to be able to delete from the dictionary every key that had an empty list as a value, but I cannot then take the deleted value and delete it from the whole dictionary
How can I do this?

Comment: One question: What happens if after key removal you get a blank list in one of the keys?

Comment: that's what I wish it would happen. in particular I would like to iterate on this until the dictionary is empty and I have all the values ​​sorted in the list

Comment: Sorted how? Is there any criteria?

Comment: @Nestor the sorting criterion is the following: in the list I insert each key that matches an empty list each time (which I then delete from the dictionary together with all its other occurrences). in this way I should have a new empty list as the value of a key (and continue like this until all the elements in the dictionary are finished)

Answer (score 2):

To delete a key-value pair from a dictionary just `del dictionary[key]`

**Updated:**

In your case:

```
dic = {(0, 0, 255): [(255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
   (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
   (0, 255, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
   (255, 255, 0): [],
   (0, 255, 255): [(255, 255, 0)]}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    to_delete = []
    for key, value in dict(dic).items():
        if len(value) == 0:
            to_delete.append(key)
            del dic[key]

    for key in dict(dic):
        dic[key] = [item for item in dic[key] if item not in to_delete]

    print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{
    (0, 0, 255): [(0, 255, 255)], 
    (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)], 
    (0, 255, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)], 
    (0, 255, 255): []
}
```

Comment: Please note that you've only answered halve of the question (deleting the key) but not the second part (deleting from the values).

Comment: it now answers the whole question.

Comment: @Nestor idk why but this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Is it giving you an error or something? I double checked and is returning the same output as requested in the question

Comment: maybe I adapted it badly to my program :(

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
list1 = [k for k, v in dic.items() if v == []]
newDict1 = {k: v for k, v in dic.items() if v != []}
newDict2 = {k: v for k, v in newDict1.items() if not any(xs in v for xs in list1)}
```

Explanation of the code:

1. list1 will keep a copy of all the blank arrays in dic
2. newDict1 will eliminate all the blank arrays from dic and save a copy
3. newDict2 will check all the remaining tuples and eliminate any tuple which contains the deleted keys as values.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_del = [k for k, v in dic.items() if len(v) == 0]
_ = [dic.pop(k) for k in to_del]
_ = [dic[k].remove(d) for k in dic.keys() for d in to_del if d in dic[k]]
print (dic)
```

Output:

```
{(0, 0, 255): [(0, 255, 255)],
 (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
 (0, 255, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)],
 (0, 255, 255): []}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the output is: {(0, 0, 255): [(0, 255, 255)],
 (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
 (0, 255, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)],
 (0, 255, 255): [(255, 255, 0)]}

Comment: @orsettomorbido are you sure ? because it gave me `{(0, 0, 255): [(0, 255, 255)],
 (255, 0, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 255)],
 (0, 255, 0): [(0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 255)],
 (0, 255, 255): []}`

Comment: maybe I adapted it badly to my program, now the problem is figuring out what was wrong :(